# Test Class Strategy

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I have an Apex Trigger:

```
Trigger CalculateACV on SBQQ__DiscountTier__c (after insert, after update) {
    (new ExpansionTierCalculator()).calculate(Trigger.new);
Tier 
}
```

ExpansionTierCalculator has one main method, inside of which there are 6 queries and 10 loops that process the queries. What data do I supply in the test class? 
Should I recreate the queries?

Ultimately, the class updates related records retrieved by the queries. Put simply, what should it do?

Thank you

Link to the class:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rg8jajohm20kxn/ExpansionTierCalculator18.java?dl=0

Comment: positive condition, negative condition and the process.. So you have 6 queries and 10 loops, you should question whether or not you need that and if by using Maps you can't get those procedures smaller and faster

Comment: If you have lots of conditions to deal with, it could be a good use case for using StaticResources to mock test data. They can be created in Excel and so are a lot easier to 'populate' than using test factories in apex

Answer (score 1):

If you will read my another answer about [what to test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115669/when-do-i-need-to-write-a-test-class/115672#115672) you will understand that every code should execute for following action

**1. Single action**

```
   Test to verify that a single record produces the correct, expected result.
```

**2. Bulk actions**

Any Apex code, whether a trigger, a class or an extension, may be invoked for 1 to 200 records. You must test not only the single record case, but the bulk cases as well.

After checking your code I can see that it will fail for bulk data because you are calling **calculate(t);** method inside for loop of Trigger.new so first you should optimized your code so that you can handle bulk data.

Now in terms of writing test method for this trigger you should know that what ever data is required for apex trigger/class should created inside the test method.

You have written trigger on **SBQQ__DiscountTier__c** object it means you should create this sObject record inside your test method. start reading your code line by line and you will get answer of your question what data you need to create.

You need records for following sobjects

1. SBQQ__DiscountSchedule__c (Line 18)
2. SBQQ__QuoteLine__c (Line 89)

Apart from that you need to cover all trigger line so you need to create valid data where you have if logic so that you can see that logic in action.

You can learn unit testing in salesforce for trigger with [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers) module